# How to output all elements with the same key from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have this array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#232 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "pdfs Shoulder"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#231 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "pdfs Shoulder"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#230 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "112"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
}
```

Using a `foreach` I will output it, but, there are 3 `type_id` keys, one with 4 and two with 7, so the output is like this:

```
Course Name: 4
   File: pdfs Shoulder
Course Name: 7
   File: pdfs Shoulder
Course Name: 7
   File: 112
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
 Course Name: 4
   File: pdfs Shoulder
Course Name: 7
   File: pdfs Shoulder
   File: 112
```

I can't figure out how to do this....
If is easier to solve modifying the query, this is the query I use:

```
SELECT lm.id,lm.name,lm.local, lmr.access as access,lmr.type_id
                FROM `media` as lm
                LEFT JOIN `mediarel` as lmr
                ON lm.id=lmr.media_id
                WHERE `lmr`.`type_id` IN ({$ids})
                AND lm.published = 1 and flag=1 and lmr.type='pmed' order by lmr.order
```

Comment: Are you using mysql? if you are, you can try using `GROUP BY` `type_id` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: maybe I dont know how to use/put them in the query, but it doesnt give me the result i need

Comment: But is mysql? Because sql server doesnt support `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: is mysql. I am not sure how to use them tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reconstruct your array with **type_id** then you can show it as you wanted. you can do as follows:

```
      //reconstructing with type id
       $sorted_courses = array();
       foreach ($array as $course) {
           $sorted_courses[$course->type_id][] = (object) array(
                       'id' => $course->id,
                       'name' => $course->name
           );
       }


       //viewing 
       foreach ($sorted_courses as $key => $files) {
           echo "Course Name: " . $key . "<br/>";
           foreach ($files as $file) {
               echo "File: " . $file->name . "<br/>";
           }
           echo "<br/>";
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to use `GROUP BY` in your query, which you should read up on and try to understand its usage.

If you simply want to work with what you have you could do this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!isset($newArray[$val->type_id])) $newArray[$val->type_id] = [];
    $newArray[$val->type_id][] = $val->name;
}
```

This will give you this:

```
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "pdfs Shoulder"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "pdfs Shoulder"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "112"
  }
}
```

You can display output like this:

```
foreach ($newArray as $k => $val) {
    echo 'Course Name: '.$k.'<br>';
    foreach ($val as $v) {
        echo '    File: '.$v.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i meant in my comment:

```
SELECT lm.id,GROUP_CONCAT(lm.name),lm.local, lmr.access as access,lmr.type_id
    FROM `media` as lm
    LEFT JOIN `mediarel` as lmr
    ON lm.id=lmr.media_id
    WHERE `lmr`.`type_id` IN ({$ids})
    AND lm.published = 1 and flag=1 and lmr.type='pmed' order by lmr.order
    GROUP BY lmr.type_id
```

You can read more about GROUP_CONCAT [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), if you want to change how the values are beeing concatenated.